# Is there a way to remove the comma from a large number generated in a batch file?

Tags: csv, batch-file, number-formatting

I have created a batch file to gather some information about different file locations and one is to get the size in bytes.  I was wondering if there was a way to remove the comma as I am creating a .csv file and opening it in excel where the separator is a comma, therefore, I am unable to view the information under the correct headings.

Can this be done?

Here's my code for getting the size:

```
ECHO OFF
    Set _size=0
    For /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%I In ('Dir !folder! /a-d /S ^|Find /I "file(s^)"') Do Set size=%%I
```

Thanks!

Comment: Once size is set, eliminate the comma using string substitution `set size=%size:,=%`

Comment: I tried that, but it displays the following when in Edit mode: `,,,,C:\Users\mmcgk\Desktop,,,,,=,152,62,13-ov-v-13`. There are supposed to be four commas before the location, four after, no equals symbol, and today's date at the end in the format DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: some language settings use a comma, others use a dot (1,245 / 1.245). Can't you use a semicolon as delimiter for your csv? That works fine with excel.

Comment: @Mark - Your comment has no bearing on the original question. It sounds like perhaps an entirely different question. Or perhaps you have misdiagnosed your problem.

Comment: another way would be to quote the string you do not want being split (and possibly post-process in Excel)

Comment: Use `/-c` in the DIR command.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone! @dbenham - What I was trying to say was that I was getting the results shown above when I edited the csv file in notepad.  Sorry for confusing you.  Stephan - Unfortunately I am unable to change settings in excel as it's for work and going to be used across many machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/-c` to the DIR command as shown below.
It will remove the commas before they become a problem in the first place.

The escape character in the find command was not needed either.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set size=0
For /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%I In ('Dir !folder! /a-d /S /-c ^|Find /I "file(s)"') Do Set size=%%I
```

Comment: +1, I don't think I ever noticed that feature before.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this comma with this code:

```
    @echo off

    For /F "tokens=* delims=," %%A in ("1234,5678") do set part1=%%A & set part2=%%B

    Echo here is your number without the comma: %part1%%part2%

    Pause > nul
    Exit
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah that's right, but if there were many commas it will remove all, but you have to add %%C... It's going to more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, `for` already provides the ability to get the size of a file:

```
set PATHOFINTEREST=C:\Windows
for /f %%x in ('dir /s/b /a-d %PATHOFINTEREST%') do @echo %%x,%%~zx
```

This will given you a comma-delimited list of filenames and their sizes.  Check `for /?` for information on all of the modifiers you can give it to pull out various attributes of a file.

Comment: The OP is looking for the sum of the file sizes of all files in the tree, not the size of each individual file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@ECHO OFF
Set _size=0
For /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%I In ('Dir !folder! /a-d /S ^|Find /I "file(s^)"') Do (Set size=%%I&set size=!size:,=!)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: if this helped you, please consider marking as correct answer

Answer (score -1):

```
::-------begin code---------
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do call :process "%%a"
goto :eof
:process
set strData=%1
set strData=%strData:,=%
for /f "delims=" %%x in (%strData%) do echo %%x >> testnew.txt
::-------end code-----------
```

Found this piece of code which worked for me. Hope it helps !